# svn to git, upgrading software, and migrating to a new vm all at once

Tags: git, svn, trac, artifactory

I have several tasks that I have been assigned to do and I'm trying to figure out the best order to accomplish them in and if there are any major pitfalls I should be aware of. Here's a list of what needs to be done:

1. Convert Subversion repositories to Git
2. Upgrade Trac to the newest version
3. Integrate Git with the upgraded Trac
4. Upgrade Artifactory
5. Move entire repository "network" (Git repos, Trac, Artifactory, etc.) to a new vm

I have basic instructions documented for each part of this puzzle, but I'm trying to figure out the best order to do these tasks in. Best part is - the powers that be want 1 repository completely converted and using upgraded versions on the new vm before any of the other repositories are touched. Long story short - my business degree just ain't cuttin' it right now.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following (note: I don't know git, Trac or Artifactory, so I'm only assuming/guessing that they'll let you do this piecemeal):

1. Put Subversion repositories into read-only mode
2. Start converting **copies** of the SVN repositories to git (so you can fall back to SVN if it goes pear-shaped)
3. Spin up new VM
4. Install the latest versions of Trac & Atrifactory on the new VM
5. Move your git repositories to the new VM
6. Integrate git & Trac

By doing this, you can do one repository at a time (only do the first 2 steps and the last 2 steps for one repository, not all at once), and always have your "old" setup available if you have to fall back.

Comment: Good plan. For points 2. and 5. I can recommend the approach described in [SVN to Git migration that works](http://svnrating.com/svn-to-git-migration/) as it worked perfectly for me.